# Blazor InteractiveServer and pre-rendering - when is OnInitializedAsync() called?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am upgrading my app from Blazor Ver 6/7 Server side to Ver 8 InteractiveServer. I want pre-rendering which will render the page scaffold/skeleton first, then we take the time to read from the DB to populate the page with data.

To summarize, [the way to have the entire app, all components (unless explicitly specified differently) to be InteractiveServer with pre-rendering on is:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78163414/509627)

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
// other stuff
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

And in App.razor:

```
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
```

So here's my question. In my testing `OnInitializedAsync()` is called exactly once. After the scaffold/skeleton is rendered. If I put a `Task.Delay()` in `OnInitializedAsync()` then it goes:

1. enter OnInitializedAsync
2. Task.Delay()
3. page skeleton displayed
4. OnAfterRenderAsync
5. OnInitializedAsync completes

This is all great. But there were issues around `OnInitializedAsync()` being called twice. Is being called twice only for SSR + Streaming? And as such, not an issue here?

And... [I went back and looked at an old question of mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759529/rendermode-interactiveserver-call-oninitializedasync-twice-how-can-i-avoid-a) In one of the early release candidates for Ver 8, for `InteractiveServer` mode, was it calling `OnInitializedAsync()` twice?

Comment: Editorial addendum - I've spent hours around the `OnInitializedAsync()` being called twice issue - and it looks like there was no need to do so. AARGH! As I understand it InteractiveServer with pre-rendering is optimum for Blazor server and it works exactly as I want - calling `OnInitializedAsync()` once, after the initial rendering. And I wasted all that time because I didn't understand this well. Although, [the documentation for render modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes) does not, IMHO, make streaming clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All correct except:

4. OnAfterRenderAsync

You're falling back into thinking of `OnAfterRenderAsync` as part of the lifecycle methods, rather than a UI Event.

This is a serious oversimplification, but consider the *Blazor Synchronisation Context* has two queues.

1. The Send/Post queue where all  *Rendering* [RenderFramgents] and *Continuations* are posted.
2. An event queue were UI events are posted.

The *synchronisation context* prioritises the post queue over the UI event queue, which dictates when `OnAfterRenderAsync` runs.

If the post queue is clear [all work queued has completed] when the renderer queues a UI event, it's run immediately.  However, if the post queue is busy and the continuation from `Task.Delay` is already posted [or posted while the queue is busy], `OnAfterRenderAsync` is not run until the post queue clears i.e. last.

Also note that if `OnInitializedAsync` yields,  the component is rendered twice, and thus `OnAfterRenderAsync` will be run twice.

Comment: As always, thank you very much.